# How to enable/disable the cron of AWS LambdaB from LambdaA

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, serverless

I have a Lambda (LoadFile) that is triggered on an S3 event. This happens once or twice a year.

After the file is loaded, at midnight, the loaded data needs to be activated. There is a lambda (ActivateData) that does that. There is an cron event that will run this lambda at midnight. The event is 'disabled' at creation.

How can the LoadFile lambda 'enable' the cron event for ActivateData lambda once it has loaded the data?

For bonus points how can the ActivateData lambda disable it's own cron event?

I'm specifically interested in doing this in Java.

The SAM template specifies the ActivateData lambda with the following:

```
  Events:
    ActivateFileDataEvent:
      Type: Schedule
      Properties:
        Schedule: cron(0 0 * * ? *)
        Description: Activates an already loaded file
        Enabled: false
```

Comment: By cron event, you mean CloudWatch Event scheduled rule?

Comment: Cant you just make LoadFileLambda call ActivateData lambda directly (without cron), in aws....perhaps I misunderstood your requirements :)

Comment: @SusanMustafa the LoadFile lambda would happen during business hours, and the ActivateData lambda must be run that night at midnight.

Comment: @Marcin The SAM template (edited above) for the ActivateData lambda sets an cron event that is disabled. I would like to enable this event from the LoadFile lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most things it is really simple once you figure it out.

In the SAM:

- store the name of the event to enable as an environment variable in the Load File Lambda
- give that lambda the requisite permissions in the policies section.

Then this piece of code did the trick. The ActivateData lambda will have to be disabled once it has run so that it does not run again every night at midnight.

```
AmazonEventBridge eventBridge = AmazonEventBridgeClientBuilder.defaultClient();
EnableRuleRequest request = new EnableRuleRequest();
request.setName(System.getenv("ACTIVATE_EVENT_NAME"));
try {
  EnableRuleResult result = eventBridge.enableRule(request);
} catch (Throwable t){
  log.error("Something went wrong, event is still disabled.",t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think cron is the most ideal way to handle this use case. For most of the time it would be in disabled state. A better approach might be to use AWS Step Functions using your existing two Lambda functions.

The Step function will contain 3 nodes -

1. LoadFile (Task node)
2. Wait Node. You can make this node wait for a fixed number of seconds.
3. ActivateData (Task Node).

Only tricky part will be to decide how long the Wait Node has to wait for. That can be decided in your LoadFile Lambda. You can get the currentTime there and calculate the number of seconds remaining before the next 12 AM. And set this value in your Step Functions state, so that the Wait node can pick it up.

If you don't want to corrupt the logic in LoadData Lambda function, you can decouple the time calculation logic in a separate Lambda function and put this new function again as a task node in your Step Function.

[image]